# How do you print fractions as text on screen?

Tags: java

This is how I am supposed to print / show fractions on screen

[image: this is how I am supposed to print / show on screen]

how do I print that on screen?

I have tried
`System.out.println("Fraction 2: 3 \n --- 8 = 0.375");`
does not work as intented in the picture

It is just a simple print line, I think I am overthinking or just not now some functions exists to print functions.

Comment: Try printing only the above line first (the one with the 3), then print the middle line and so on...

Comment: Do you have to print just that exact content, or do you really need to be able to take some input and output arbitrary expressions involving fractions?  If it's the former, then just realize that you have to print 3 lines to get the desired result.  You only have one `\n` in your `println` call, so that won't print 3 lines.  If you need a general fraction expression printer, that's going to involve a lot of work unless you can find a module that already does this (and you're allowed to use it).

Comment: You have to create and print each line of your output one line at a time.  You can't just print each fraction individually.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, in order to have the numerator appear in the line above, you have to print that line first. Try this out, it's not perfect but it should work:

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    private float result;

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
        result = (float) numerator / (float) denominator;
    }

    // The msg is optional here
    public void print(String msg) {
        // Print space for each character in the string
        for (int i = 0; i <= msg.length(); ++i)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(" "+ numerator);
        System.out.println(msg + " --- = " + result);
        for (int i = 0; i <= msg.length(); ++i)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(" "+ denominator);
    }
}
```

And here's the main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction fraction = new Fraction(3, 8);
        fraction.print("Fraction 2:");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
             3
Fraction 2: --- = 0.375
             8
```

If you have to print various fractions at once, you could write a class that takes various functions as an input and prints them all.

Also if you have to print fractions with numerators or denominators larger than one digit, you'll need to modify this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can build logic with use of `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`
`commons-lang3` or `commons-lang` has many other Utils classes.

Some useful `StringUtils` methods which you can refer:

```
StringUtils.center("a", 4)      //returns " a  "
StringUtils.rightPad("bat", 5)  //returns "batzz"
StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 5)   //returns "  bat"
```

Refer java-doc of the class for more examples and reference. Happy Coding!!